# How to delete this hotkey/keyboard-shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, vbscript

I've made a hotkey/keyboard-shortcut that does the same thing when you right-click on the desktop. My goal wasn't that at all. So I want to delete this hotkey, but I don't know how to. The hotkey is actually Shift+F10. The way I made the hotkey was a .vbs file. Here it is:

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys("^ ")

WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")

WshShell.SendKeys("n")

Comment: Delete the vbs file and restart the PC.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It didn't work.